# How do I click a button that will remove an item from a ListBox and the List that holds the information for the ListBox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, class, collections

I have to use a `ListBox` for this.

I currently know how to remove from a `ListBox` using this code:

```
private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    REMOVE();
}

private void REMOVE()
{
    int c = lstCart.Items.Count - 1;

    for (int i = c; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (lstCart.GetSelected(i))
        {
            lstCart.Items.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

But what I have found is that when I add another item, it clears the `ListBox` and shows each item from the list, so it includes the 'removed' item because it wasn't removed from the list, only the `ListBox`.
I'm thinking that what I need to do is remove the selected line from the List, then clear the `ListBox` and repopulate it with the updated List data. But I'm struggling to find out how to do this.

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OrderItem currentItem = new OrderItem(txtItemName.Text,
        Decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text), (int)numQTY.Value);
        myBasket.Add(currentItem);
        lstCart.Items.Clear();
        foreach (OrderItem i in myBasket)
        {
            lstCart.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,-40}  
            {1,-40}  {2,-40}  {3,-40}", i.ProductName, 
            i.Quantity.ToString(), i.LatestPrice.ToString(),
            i.TotalOrder.ToString()));
        }
        txtItemTotal.Text = "£" + myBasket.BasketTotal.ToString();
        txtItemCount.Text = myBasket.Count.ToString();
    }

    private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int c = lstCart.Items.Count - 1;

        for (int i = c; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (lstCart.GetSelected(i))
            {
                lstCart.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        ????
    }
}
```

ShoppingBasket class:

```
public class ShoppingBasket
{
    public ShoppingBasket()
    {

    }

    public new void Add(OrderItem i)
    {
        base.Add(i);
        calcBasketTotal();
    }

    private void calcBasketTotal()
    {
        BasketTotal = 0.0M;
        foreach (OrderItem i in this)
        {
            BasketTotal += i.TotalOrder;
        }
    }

    public new void Remove(OrderItem i)
    {
        ????
    }
}
```

OrderItem class:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public OrderItem(string productName, 
    decimal latestPrice, int quantity)
    {
        ProductName = productName;
        LatestPrice = latestPrice;
        Quantity = quantity;
        TotalOrder = latestPrice * quantity;
    }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public decimal LatestPrice { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Instead of removing the item from the listbox, why not remove the item from the underlying data (the list) and then databind the control

Comment: What is base? base.Add(i); Do the same for remove.

Comment: @SpaceBison How would I databind the control? And to remove it from the list would I have to use the same format as I have added it to the list? Would you create a new instance of OrderItem for this?

Comment: @SamLeach How would I call that though? Would I use the GetSelected() to determine the entry I want to delete for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your add method calls `Add(`) on a base class. Do you have a remove on your base class? If so, use that. Otherwise change your `ShoppingBasket` class to be:

The `Orders` list stores your `OrderItems`. Add and Remove from this list.

```
public class ShoppingBasket
{
    public List<OrderItem> Orders { get; set; }

    public ShoppingBasket()
    {
        Orders = new List<OrderItem>();
    }

    public void Add(OrderItem orderItem)
    {
        Orders.Add(orderItem);
    }


    public void Remove(OrderItem orderItem)
    {
        Orders.Remove(orderItem);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var basket = new ShoppingBasket();
basket.Add( new OrderItem { OrderItemId = 1, ... } );

// Remove an OrderItem
basket.Remove( new OrderItem { OrderItemId = 1 } );
```